# Unable to initialize the chrome driver in the latest selenium 3.x

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Version: Selenium 3.0.1
OS: Windows 10, Eclipse neon

Unable to initialize the chrome driver in the latest selenium 3.x same code works fine with 2.53.x, the stacktrace is copied below, seems like ApacheHttpClient reference is broken.  anyideas?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:120)
    at last.test.main(test.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.auth.Credentials
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: How are you running your tests? Through an IDE or command line?

Comment: through IDE , its eclipse neon, i am calling my tests from a testng xml file

Answer (score 0):

A NoClassDefFoundError almost always means that you are missing a library on the classpath. The versions of libraries required may have changed with Selenium 3 - make sure your classpath includes all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue while using Chrome driver with selenium 3.0.1 on my Windows 10 machine.

Download older version selenium webdriver from [Selenium Downlaod](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).
Search for **jcommander-1.48.jar** from the downloaded zip file and add this jar into your current project.

This should fix the *NoClassDefFoundErro*r and your project should compile successfully.

Comment: Thanks Saurav, jcommander did not work for me, seems like it is a dependency for testng, anyways so i tried adding the http client jar as dependency still the same issue.... seems the reference to http client jar is broken for some reason. any more ideas ??